# Physically passing through a pin to access another

Tags: esp8266, atmega328, pins

I would like to know about physically passing through a pin in order to get to another. For instance, if I have a sensor on one side of an ATMEGA328P or ESP8266 (Wemos D1 Mini) yet need to connect to a pin on the other side, would I be able to simply go through an unused pin instead of worrying about going around or using a jumper wire? If so, would I need to set the unused pin in a certain way, for example as an input (with or without pull-up)?

PS: The diagram  of the first answer illustrates my question exactly and the answer has been accepted as the solution.

Comment: It is unclear to me, what exactly your problem is. Why would you need to "go through a pin" (whatever that means) to access another pin? The pins are all spaced out. Why are you not able to reach the pin, that you want to connect?

Comment: No.  If you want to connect to a certain pin then you need to connect to that pin.  The pins are physically connected to certain parts of the chip.  They're not re-routable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I understand what you are asking. You want to connect **both** the relevant pin and an unrelated one, like in this DIP footprint:

[image: passing through another pin]

If this is the case, the answer is yes, provided that the pass-through pin is always held in a high-impedance (i.e. `INPUT`) state.

Comment: This is exactly the answer to the question at hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the unused pin isn't configured for any conflicting functions like SPI, I2C, or UART communication, as this could interfere with the signal you're routing.

Comment: Thanks. I thought as much that is why I referred to the pin as unused, but I guess I didn't clarify p0roperly.